# Adding collision to a png image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development, collision

so Im developing a web game in JavaScript, and I want to add collision to some objects in the map. The map was created using the Desktop App called Tiled, and I exported the map as a png image.
Also on Tiled I drawed the collision blocks for all the objects in a separated layer and exported that layer as a png as well.

So now in my game I have the map and the collision block displayed one under the other, and I want to use this collision png image (that has only the red squares for reference the collision in it) to make the collision with the player.

this is how I import the images:

```
const gameMap = new Image();
gameMap.src = './img/PGM.png'

const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = './img/player/idle-test.png'

const collisionMap = new Image();
collisionMap.src = './img/collision.png'
```

they all have a Sprite class:

```
class Sprite {
    constructor({
        position,
        velocity,
        image
    }) {
        this.position = position
        this.image = image
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y);
    }
}
```

and this is how they are initialized:

```
const background = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: offset.x,
        y: offset.y
    },
    image: gameMap
})

const collision = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: offset.x,
        y: offset.y
    },
    image: collisionMap
})
```

the game is working fine, the movimentation, the drawing of the sprites on the screen... But I dont know how to use the collision image as real collision with the player.

Making a png Image with red squares that references collision with objects, work as real collision with the player in my game.

Comment: Im gonna look it, thank you!